# XML: Cannot load even when string is escaped

Tags: php, xml

I have big problem, I cant load XML file even when every special char is escaped. My XML:

```
    <code1>
    <code>&lt;?php
        // create curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, &quot;example.com&quot;);

        //return the transfer as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);
?&gt;</code>
</code1>
```

When I insert in `<code></code>` another string, ex. `Hello world`, it works. Why it doesnt work? BTW, I am using `PHP's simplexml_load_file`. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any sort of error message or unexpected result?

Comment: @adrel, no i dont get anything.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the contents in CDATA and calling simplexml_load_file with LIBXML_NOCDATA as the third argument?

Comment: @andrel, thank you so much, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By wrapping the contents in a CDATA block, you can make the XML parser (PHP) ignore the contents. By calling `simplexml_load_file` with `LIBXML_NOCDATA` as the third argument, PHP will return the contents within the CDATA block, but will not interfere with the contents (escaping characters).

So, the solution is wrapping the XML contents in a CDATA-block:

```
<code1>
    <code>
        <![CDATA[contents with special characters]]>
    </code>
</code1>
```

and load the file in PHP by using:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file_xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```